# intellij doesnt show my git branch

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I already tried other posts on the web, checking all the toolbar and still, it doesn't show my git branch (in the right down corner)

Any idea why and how i can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Are your file in a git repo?

Comment: yep.. i can push and pull and everything works fine
it's just that there's no indication of what im currently working on